# Custom directory for cron commands

Tags: linux, cron

I'm using `vixie` cron on Debian/Ubuntu. How to set a custom directory to be read by cron? I want to lead crontab to run commands found in a series of files, e.g.

```
/home/cron/*.cron
```

or perfectly

```
/home/*/cron/*.*
```

In fact, instead of putting cron commands in `/var/spool/cron/crontab/root`, I want to spread commands in these folder.

Is it possible and recommended to use `include` for calling other files within `root` file?

Comment: @Mat, I'm using Debian/Ubuntu; thus, the default cron is `vixie`, if it's what you mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cron in debian reads commands from 3 locations - first is users crontabs in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$user`, then it reads global `/etc/crontab` and then all files from `/etc/cron.d`.

But you can't easily have multiple crontabs per user. Only files in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` are per-user. The other two are system-wide and each line contains a username, under which is the command run. You could integrate/link those individual files into `/etc/cron.d`, but users would be able to run commands under root or other user.

So if one crontab per user is OK, just make links from your location to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. If you need multiple per user, then you need to make a script which will take your users's cron files, and modify it for system-wide crontab (that means adding a field with their username) and adding those under `/etc/cron.d`.